# Two-edge-colouring of $K_{5,5}$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am not sure right now but why does every two-edge-colouring of $K_{5,5}$ has either a red or a blue matching of size $3$? Normally a complete bipartite graph $K_{r,s}$ has a maximum matching size of $\min\{r,s\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have LHS vertices and RHS vertices. Each of LHS vertices has degree 5, so either it has at least 3 red vertices or at least 3 blue vertices. Color a vertex red if it has at least 3 red edges or blue if it has at least 3 blue edges. Now there are at least 3 LHS vertices of the same color, say blue. And each of them is connected to at least 3 RHS vertices with blue edges. Now you can greedily match these vertices.